# Does a free proton shrink when accelerated?

Tags: charge, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics, protons, particle-accelerators

Reading about the [charge radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_radius) of the proton and [proton radius puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_radius_puzzle) I started  wondering if the cross section and therefore also the charge radius (i.e. size of proton) changes or more specifically becomes smaller when free protons in a beam are accelerated by any linear or any synchrotron accelerator like the LHC for example.

I am not referring to the SR length contraction effect but if this is happening also in lower non relativistic speeds. Does in general the proton shrink when accelerated?

Comment: Why would an accelerated proton shrink? What would the mechanism be?

Comment: https://indico.cern.ch/event/628450/contributions/2831156/attachments/1583184/2502131/HEP_Chile_Form_Factor_Liyanage.pdf after page 27  see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton#Charge_radius

Comment: @annav Great info collection. Thanks!